# "Add to cart" redirect to WooCommerce checkout based on product category

Tags: wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, product, taxonomy-terms

I have a scenario where I want to skip the cart page and go directly to WooCommerce checkout. I want to test only on specific categories.

So this is working (from multisite child functions):

```php
function skip_cart_page () {
    global $woocommerce;
    $redirect_to_checkout = $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url();

    return $redirect_to_checkout;                  
 }   
 add_filter('add_to_cart_redirect', 'skip_cart_page');
```

And this is not:

```php
if( has_term( 'test', 'product_cat' ) ) { 
    echo "Test cat";
}
```

I want to achieve:

```php
 if( has_term( 'test', 'product_cat' ) ) {
    add_filter('add_to_cart_redirect', 'skip_cart_page');
}
```

And don't know why `has_term` doesn't work outside of function?

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains some mistakes/shortcomings or outdated code:

- `add_to_cart_redirect` is deprecated since version 3.0.0! Use `woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect` instead.
- Use `wc_get_checkout_url()` vs `$woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url()`
- `$redirect_url` and `$product` are passed to the `woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect` hook

So you get:

```php
// Redirect
function filter_woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect( $redirect_url, $product ) {
    // Specific categories: the term name/term_id/slug. Several could be added, separated by a comma
    $categories = array( 63, 15, 'categorie-1', 'test' );

    // Contains the definite term
    if ( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
        $redirect_url = wc_get_checkout_url();
    }

    return $redirect_url;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'filter_woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: thanks for answer. after solving problem with "Call to a member function get_id() on null" function doesn't redirect to checkout:/